# label inside combobox and conditional multiselect

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, combobox, multi-select

I am building a pretty combobox with checkboxes and conditional entries. Everything works out alright, except for two features that I cannot figure out how to implement.

1) I would like to move the label inside the combobox, make it shift the values to the right, and appear in a slightly gray color.

2) I would like the value to ignore certain entries (group headers) selected. Those entries are there for functionality only - to select/unselect groups of other entries.

The entire project is in the zip file. You don't need a server, it's a client base app. Just download the archive, unpack, and launch app.html in your browser.

http://filesave.me/file/30586/project-zip.html

And here's a snapshot of what I would like to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second issue, the best way I see is to override combobox `onListSelectionChange` to filter the values you don't want:

```
onListSelectionChange: function(list, selectedRecords) {
    //Add the following line
    selectedRecords = Ext.Array.filter(selectedRecords, function(rec){
        return rec.data.parent!=0;
    });
    //Original code unchanged from here
    var me = this,
        isMulti = me.multiSelect,
        hasRecords = selectedRecords.length > 0;
    // Only react to selection if it is not called from setValue, and if our list is
    // expanded (ignores changes to the selection model triggered elsewhere)
    if (!me.ignoreSelection && me.isExpanded) {
        if (!isMulti) {
            Ext.defer(me.collapse, 1, me);
        }
        /*
         * Only set the value here if we're in multi selection mode or we have
         * a selection. Otherwise setValue will be called with an empty value
         * which will cause the change event to fire twice.
         */
        if (isMulti || hasRecords) {
            me.setValue(selectedRecords, false);
        }
        if (hasRecords) {
            me.fireEvent('select', me, selectedRecords);
        }
        me.inputEl.focus();
    }
},
```

And change your `onBoundlistItemClick` to only select and deselect items in the `boundlist` not to `setValue` of the combo:

```
onBoundlistItemClick: function(dataview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    var chk = item.className.toString().indexOf('x-boundlist-selected') == -1;

    if ( ! record.data.parent) {    
        var d = dataview.dataSource.data.items;
        for (var i in d) {
            var s = d[i].data;
            if (s.parent == record.data.id) {
                if (chk) { // select
                     dataview.getSelectionModel().select(d[i],true);
                } else { // deselect
                     dataview.getSelectionModel().deselect(d[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Regarding your first issue, it is easy to add the label using the displayTpl config option. But this will only add the text you need, without any style (grey color, etc). The combo is using a text input, which does not accept html tags. If you don't need the user to type text, than you may want to change the combo basic behavior and use another element instead of the text input.